# Estimation of a function of a random vector

Tags: probability, optimization, statistical-inference, machine-learning

The joint probability distribution of the random variables $X_1$, $X_2$, ..., $X_n$ is available. The objective is to find the distribution of $\epsilon = g(X_1, X_2, ...,X_n)$. In other words, $g$ is unknown. A sample of size $m$ is drawn from the population: $([X_{i1}, X_{i2},..., X_{in}], \epsilon_i)$ is available for $i=1,...,m$. How to find $\epsilon^*$ such that $P(\epsilon>\epsilon^*)<0.05$. On a more general note, how to find an optimized estimator of $g$, namely $\hat{g}$?

Probably a common problem for professionals in this field but I'm a beginner, so your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you are asking more or less for statistical machine learning, which is a huge discipline. Maybe if you gave us information about what random variables and what data you are dealing with, I could give you a suggestion for what method to use.

Comment: Assume $\epsilon$ a random variable related to the measurement accuracy of a sensor. The random variables $X_i$ are the operating conditions which can affect the sensor accuracy e.g. $X_1$ being the temperature, $X_2$ pressure, etc. The joint distribution of the operating conditions is readily available. The objective is to find a accuracy threshold  $\epsilon^*$ for the sensor in a way that the measurement error above this threshold occurs only at operating conditions with probability of occurrence less than 5%.

Comment: I think, you also need some assumptions about the function $g$. Without any assumption, you know the function $g$ only at given points and the rest is up to your fantasy. The fact that you know the function at one point doesn't tell you anything about how the function looks like in a different point.

Answer (score 1):

I have a suggestion for what method you can use. As I said in the comment, you have no assumption about the function $g$, so this sollution is more likely heuristic, assuming that the function $g$ is nice with respect to this method.

When you are given a point $[X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots]$ and you need to calculate $g(X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots)$, you take the measurements within radius $R$ and estimate the 0.95-quantile of them. You just need to fit the radius $R$ to your data, so it gives satisfactory results. Or more generally, you weighten all measurements by a kernel function of your choice (a non-increasing function of distance between two points). Again, you have to choose a fitting kernel function.

If you choose a kernel function which is infinite for zero distance (for example inverted square distance), it will have a special effect. If you are given a measurement at a point and then you ask for the same point, the measurement at that point will outweight all other points, so you get the measurement which you got.